# Merge two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have recently started using dataframes in Python and I don't know how can I do the following exercise.

I have two dataframes, both with the same columns (`Type` column and `Count` column) like this:

`main_df`:

| Index | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Album | 12 |
| 1 | Book | 4 |
| 2 | Person | 3 |

`df2`:

| Index | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Album | 9 |
| 1 | Person | 4 |
| 2 | Film | 4 |

Same `Type` value can have different `Index` value, as you can see with `Type = Person` (`Index = 2` in `main_df` and `Index = 1` in `df2`).

I want to have all data in `main_df`. In this case result will be:

`main_df`:

| Index | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Album | 21 |
| 1 | Book | 4 |
| 2 | Person | 7 |
| 3 | Film | 4 |

If `Type` column value in `df2` is already in `main_df`, simply sum the corresponding `Count` value of `df2`.
If `Type` column value in `df2` is not in `main_df`, add that row (`Type` and `Count` value) at the end of `main_df`.

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `pd.concat` and then use `groupby`:

```
main_df = pd.concat([main_df,df2]).groupby('Type', sort=False).agg({'Count': sum}).reset_index()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
     Type  Count
0   Album     21
1    Book      4
2  Person      7
3    Film      4
```

Answer (score 2):

try via `append()`,`groupby()` and `sum()`:

```
out=(df1.append(df2)
        .groupby('Type',as_index=False,sort=False)
        .sum())
```

Output of `out`:

```
    Type    Index   Count
0   Album   0       21
1   Book    1       4
2   Person  3       7
3   Film    2       4
```